# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component when i try to update isAdmin in useEffect()

Tags: node.js, reactjs

getting this warning in console when i try to get the data of an admin by an auth get request.

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I need to match the jwt token and get the data to verify if the person is authorized or not. Here is my code

```
    //admin private route    
    const AdminRoute = ({ component: Component, render, ...rest }) => {
     const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["x-auth"] = localStorage.getItem(
      "admintoken"
    );
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/api/adminauth")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setIsAdmin(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        setIsAdmin(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (isAdmin === false) return <Redirect to="/" />;
        return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: You're setting state inside an asynchronous function. The component could have unmounted by the time you try and set state, which is why you're getting the error. You need to check to see if the component is still mounted before trying to set state.

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: Just to clarify. Is the data you are using to determine whether user is admin or not coming from the api call response data

Comment: yes the api call is to check if the token is valid or not and which admin is accessing the dashboard